# What is this pseudocode intended to do?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, pseudocode

```
// L is a list and n is its length //

// we assume that n= 4**k , for k≥1//

Alg1(L,n)
  remove the smallest and largest element from L 
  if n-2 > (4**k)/2
  call Alg1(L, n-2)
```

Not what it does but what is it intended to do? I don't understand what the question means by "intended" but I think the algorithm just removes the largest and smallest element of the list recursively until `4` or `3` elements remain.

Comment: its not returning anything, nor editing any variables in the "function"

Answer (score 3):

Given a starting list of size 4^k, which appears to be implied by the definition  given for `n`, `alg1` reduces the size of the supplied list to ((4^k) / 2) + 2 for k >= 1. I agree with @Ctznkane525 that the algorithm is incompletely specified in that it doesn't tell us what the return value should be. But if we make the simple assumption that two elements should be removed from the end of the list each time n is decremented by 2 we can continue. Thus, consider the following implementation in Clojure:

```
(defn exp [x n]
  (reduce * (repeat n x)))

(def k 1)

(defn alg1[l n]
  (println "k=" k "  n=" n "  l=" l)
  (if (> (- n 2) (/ (exp 4 k) 2))
    (recur (take (- n 2) l) (- n 2))
    l))
```

I've added code here to print the values of k, n, and l so we can watch what happens at each step.

Given the above we'll start a little testing. We'll invoke `alg1` as `(alg1 (take (exp 4 k) (iterate #(+ 1 %) 1)) (exp 4 k))`, which simply creates a list of 4^k elements and passes it as the first argument to `alg1`, and passes 4^k for the second argument. So here goes:

```
user=> (def k 1)
#'user/k
user=> (alg1 (take (exp 4 k) (iterate #(+ 1 %) 1)) (exp 4 k))
k= 1   n= 4   l= (1 2 3 4)
(1 2 3 4)
```

So with k=1 and the list defined as `(1 2 3 4)` the function returns immediately, because n-2 = 2, and that's less than or equal to (4^k)/2, which is also 2.

Let's try with k=2:

```
user=> (def k 2)
#'user/k
user=> (alg1 (take (exp 4 k) (iterate #(+ 1 %) 1)) (exp 4 k))
k= 2   n= 16   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16)
k= 2   n= 14   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14)
k= 2   n= 12   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12)
k= 2   n= 10   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

Ah, that's a bit more interesting. We start with n=16, which is of course 4^k = 4^2 = 16, and the beginning list is (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16). When these values are considered by `alg1` it finds that n-2 (14) is greater than (4^2)/2 (8), so it trims two elements from the end of the list and recursively invokes itself. On the second iteration it finds that n-2 (12) is greater than 8 so it trims another two elements and recursively invokes itself. This continues until n=10, when `alg1` finds that n-2 (8) is no longer greater than (4^2)/2 (8), so it returns the list `(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)`.

What happens with k=3?

```
user=> (def k 3)
#'user/k
user=> (alg1 (take (exp 4 k) (iterate #(+ 1 %) 1)) (exp 4 k))
k= 3   n= 64   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64)
k= 3   n= 62   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62)
k= 3   n= 60   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60)
k= 3   n= 58   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58)
k= 3   n= 56   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56)
k= 3   n= 54   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54)
k= 3   n= 52   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52)
k= 3   n= 50   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50)
k= 3   n= 48   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48)
k= 3   n= 46   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46)
k= 3   n= 44   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44)
k= 3   n= 42   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42)
k= 3   n= 40   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40)
k= 3   n= 38   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38)
k= 3   n= 36   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36)
k= 3   n= 34   l= (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34)
```

Similar results to the above. At each iteration two elements are trimmed from the list until the condition specified in the algorithm is reached, at which point the algorithm exits.

You can continue bumping up the value of k, building the arguments, and watching the algorithm work, but in the end the results are always similar: the list is reduced in size to ((4^k) / 2) + 2.

Best of luck.